# SQL statement to order customer by sales ranking based on total sales

Tags: mysql, sql

### UPDATE:
Solved, thank you guys so much for your input. My question was badly written and I will remember my mistakes.
Next time I ask a question, I will try to avoid my mistakes.
Thank you

So I have a few tables (m_member, m_product, t_sales, t_sales_detail, rank) and I wrote a query to get the total sum of all orders per customer

```
SELECT m.name AS m_name, IFNULL(SUM(d.num * p.price), 0) AS price
FROM m_member as m
LEFT JOIN t_sales AS t ON m.id = t.m_id
INNER JOIN m_product as p
LEFT JOIN t_sales_detail as d ON t.id = d.id AND p.id = d.p_id
GROUP BY m.id;
```

The result is the following:

```
'Kawashima', '2620'
'Kawata', '0'
'Yamada', '15420'
'Nagaoku', '500'
'Nagayama', '380'
```

Now I want the order these five customers based on the ranking in the following table:

```
# id, name, low_limit, up_limit
'1', 'Pity', '0', '0'
'2', 'Bronze', '1', '4999'
'3', 'Silver', '5000', '9999'
'4', 'Gold', '10000', '999999999'
```

For example customer named Kawashima has a ordered a total of '2620円'.
Therefore his ranking should be 'Bronze'.

The result should be the following:

```
# name, rank
'Kawata', '<custom message>'
'Nagayama', 'Bronze'
'Nagaoku', 'Bronze'
'Kawashima', 'Bronze'
'Yamada', 'Gold'
```

Oh and I would like to use a subquery.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You should redesign your model and store ranking boundaries as numbers, not as strings that contain numbers. With this model you need to convert your strings to numbers with every query and can face conversion issues (for example, when different country settings were used on `insert`).

Comment: I am sorry my bad! I just added the tag. I also will read your linked question to avoid future mistakes.

Comment: You can join to the ranking table using BETWEEN https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp but as @astentx said if the values are actually stored as characters you'll need to do conversions.

Comment: @astentx We got this database sample from our teacher, so I cant really change anything. I am struggling since hours on this problem now.

Comment: @TeaBubble Are that numbers really strings or you just cannot manage to format them in appropriate way in question's text? It really makes sence (because as I see you do `sum` which returns number, but you format it as string).

Comment: Note that GROUP BY combined with JOINs requires extra care. You can end up with a much bigger result than expected, depending on the type of relationships.

Comment: @astentx Yes you are right, my bad. Stings are not used! I copied the table from MySQL Workbench and it seems that Quotation marks are added automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT X.M_NAME,X.PRICE,RN.NAME 
  FROM
 (      
    SELECT m.name AS m_name, IFNULL(SUM(d.num * p.price), 0) AS price
    FROM m_member as m
    LEFT JOIN t_sales AS t ON m.id = t.m_id
    INNER JOIN m_product as p
    LEFT JOIN t_sales_detail as d ON t.id = d.id AND p.id = d.p_id
    GROUP BY m.id
)AS X
JOIN RANK_TABLE AS RN ON X.PRICE BETWEEN RN.LOW_LIMIT AND RN.UP_LIMIT
```

Could you please try something like this

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Reading your query, I think I know now what my mistake was!

Answer (score -1):

```
Select m.id, m.name, price, isnull(rank.name, "No rank") from(SELECT m.id, m.name AS m_name, IFNULL(SUM(d.num * p.price), 0) AS price
FROM m_member as m
LEFT JOIN t_sales AS t ON m.id = t.m_id
INNER JOIN m_product as p
LEFT JOIN t_sales_detail as d ON t.id = d.id AND p.id = d.p_id
GROUP BY m.id)as result left join rank on price <= rank.up_limit and price >= rank.low_limit
```

Comment: Thank you too! Now that I have seen two approaches to solve this problem, I think understand better what I did wrong.